# GKE cluster migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-kubernetes-engine

Do any one know what is the best way to migrate #GKE cluster and the workflow to a new #VPC or project. I see that the only way to #migrate is to duplicate the cluster and change the network settings. But for the #workload I am not sure if doing it manually is the best way as we may forget some files or secrets. Is #Velero a good candidate to use? is it safe to use
bests,

Answer (score 0):

GKE has a backup [tool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/add-on/backup-for-gke/concepts/backup-for-gke). It's in Preview so use at your own risk.

Velero is also a good option. I never used it myself, but i guess as long as you keep both clusters up and running while you do the backup/restore and  check the new cluster before you delete the old one. You should be good to go with Velero